# How to grant server admin access right on SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssas

I want to provide admin access rights to an account on SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) server through code (C# or SQL script). [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/grant-server-admin-rights-to-an-analysis-services-instance) is how we do it through SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

I want to achieve the same through SQL query or may be C# code if it is possible. I searched a lot but I'm not getting anything very relevant.

I've one administrator user which already has the access on the SSAS server. So, I can fire any SQL or MDX query on the SSAS server which results in adding other user as administrator on the SSAS server.

For initial pointers, if I want to achieve the same in SQL Server instance then it is all about firing a few system-defined stored procedures like `sp_addrolemember` to grant access to any SQL Server database as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3998649/465053). I'm trying to achieve something similar if at all it is possible through code for an SSAS server.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422425/) should get you started, though we could do with a single answer.

Comment: Well, you found the time to re-edit the tags multiple times. Anyway, it would help to post something on the relevant [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356097/limit-access-to-this-tag-burninate-or-merge-with-access-control) before starting the removal. I would just have removed the tag if I had known what you were doing. @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 0):

Here is the batch that adds DOMAIN\user in the Administrators role of an SSAS Instance.

```
<Batch xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine' Transaction='true'>
<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object />
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <Server xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
      <ID>HOST</ID>
      <Name>SSAS_INSTANCE</Name>
    </Server>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <RoleID>Administrators</RoleID>
  </Object>
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <Role xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
      <ID>Administrators</ID>
      <Name>Administrators</Name>
      <Members>
        <Member>
          <Name>DOMAIN\user</Name>
        </Member>
      </Members>
    </Role>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
</Batch>
```